# Is Spring Integration Aggregator single threaded execution

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-integration

I am using splitter aggregator pattern in my application.
I have the following configuration -

```
<int:splitter inputChannel="CH1" outputChannel="CH2" ref="foo" method="bar"/>
<int:aggregator inputChannel="CH2" outputChannel="CH3" ref="oof" method="rab" ---other required configurations/>
<task:scheduler --with threadpool of size 30 />
<!--there are other channels as well. Some are queue and some are direct channels-->
```

All my channels(CH1, CH2,CH3) are `QueueChannel`. 
Source to the Splitter input channel CH1 is a file.

In my testing, I observed that even If add two files in the CH1 channel, only 1 file was being processed at a given time. So I added a Poller to my CH1 channel and now multiple input messages on CH1 channels are getting processed concurrently.

On the Aggregator side as well, I am observing that execution is always single threaded i.e. until first thread completes execution, second thread doesn't start execution.

What I have tried so far to solve this -

1. Adding poller to the `<int:aggregate>` config
2. Adding poller to the input channel CH2 (input to aggregator)
3. Adding dispatcher to the input Channel CH2

Can someone help me make the aggregator processing multithreaded as well.

**Update1**
What I am trying to do:

I recieve files containing stock data. I create message for each file and put it in CH1 channel. CH1 channel has a splitter which splits it into individual records and send it to CH2 channel.
CH2 channel has a aggregator associated with it which will try to aggregate records based on the file name and 'oof.rab'  writes the records in database. My expectation is to see multiple batches of the same file being concurrently written to database.

**Update2:**
Aggregation is done here to batch the lines, so that we can write it out to database in batch mode rather than writing the lines individually

Answer (score 0):

The aggregator is multithreaded but only for different message groups (correlation). Each group has to be single threaded since for each message arrival we have to consult the ReleaseStrategy.

Comment: Assuming correlation logic is based on file name. From what I am understanding, aggregator might process batches of messages for two different files concurrently, but for a single file, its batches would be processed serially i.e. one batch after another

Comment: If this understanding is correct, aggregator would never scale

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do; the aggregation is normally a small part of the flow - there is normally more work going on between the splitter and the aggregator. Perhaps you can explain your complete use case so we can understand what you are trying to do and perhaps make other suggestions. The aggregator scales well, but each individual aggregation necessarily is single-threaded.

Comment: It's not clear why you need an aggregator at all, why not just use a service-activator to write the records, rather than waiting for them all to be aggregated into a message group first?

Comment: Splitter component splits the file and returns the lines. Rather than writing the individual lines one by one to the database, using aggregator I am batching the lines (to reduce the number of db round trips and hence potentially increase the performance)

Comment: I have no problems with the splitter; it's the aggregator that I don't believe you need - why do you need to wait for the lines to be reassembled into a message group before writing them to the DB?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169681/discussion-between-rachit-agrawal-and-gary-russell).